# Set style with eventsetter in resources programmatically

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I need to apply style in grid resources programmatically in code behind.

I've the following snippet of code :

```
<Grid x:Name="grid">
    <Grid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ig:LabelPresenter}">
            <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseMove" Handler="LabelPresenter_PreviewMouseMove"/>
        </Style>
    </Grid.Resources>
    .
    .
    .
</Grid>
```

I want to create the `Style` in code behind and add this to resources for handle the relative action.

I tried to do this in this way but it dosen't work.

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    var style = new Style { TargetType = typeof(LabelPresenter) };
    var eventSetter = new EventSetter(PreviewMouseMoveEvent, new MouseButtonEventHandler(LabelPresenter_PreviewMouseMove));
    style.Setters.Add(eventSetter);
    grid.Resources.Add("style", style);
}
```

Where I'm wrong?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I wrote wrong grid's name. The grid's right name is **grid**

Comment: I've updated the snippet. The grid's name is "grid"

Comment: What *"dosen't work"*?

Comment: The "LabelPresenter_PreviewMouseMove" method is fired when I explicit the style in xaml, while it insn't fired when I try to add the style in code behind.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The style defined in the XAML markup is implicit, i.e. it has no `x:Key`. So change the first argument that you are passing to the `Add` method to `typeof(LabelPresenter)`.

Also, a `PreviewMouseMove` event handler accepts a `MouseEventArgs`:

```
var style = new Style { TargetType = typeof(LabelPresenter) };
var eventSetter = new EventSetter(PreviewMouseMoveEvent, new MouseEventHandler(LabelPresenter_PreviewMouseMove));
style.Setters.Add(eventSetter);
grid.Resources.Add(typeof(LabelPresenter), style);
```